# Difference between two cumulative distribution functions

Tags: statistics, binomial-distribution

Is it possible to rewrite the difference between two binomial cumulative distribution functions, one with parameter $n$ and $p$ and the second with parameter $n$ and $(1-p)$, in such a way that the equation can be written in terms of only one function? Something like that
$$
F_{n,p}(x) - F_{n,1-p}(x) = F_{n,p}(x) - (1 - F_{n,p}(x) )
$$

Comment: Not in general: the left hand side is identically zero for $p=1/2$ whereas the right hand side is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close. I think it is:

$$F_{n,p}(x) - F_{n,1-p}(x) = F_{n,p}(x) - (1 - F_{n,p}(n-\lfloor x\rfloor - 1)).$$